# What's the best method to raid1 a btrfs and efi boot drive?

Tags: linux, uefi, btrfs, raid, raid1

I have two NVME drives, one of which is already working as I want and I boot off of it: it has two partitions one for EFI, one for the BTRFS Linux filesystem.

```
Device           Start        End    Sectors  Size Type
/dev/nvme0n1p1    2048    1050623    1048576  512M EFI System
/dev/nvme0n1p2 1050624 3907028991 3905978368  1.8T Linux filesystem
```

I have another NVME `/dev/nvme1n1` which is currently unpartitioned.

Both NVME drives are the same make and model. I would like to have it so the other device is RAID1 with this device such that I can boot of it in the event of a drive failure. But I'm unsure of how to do this.

Since I'm using btrfs, I suppose I could copy the partition table from one device to the other and then add the second partition `nvme1n1p2` to the BTRFS raid1 with `btrfs device add`. But then how do you keep the EFI in sync?

What's the best method to raid1 a btrfs and efi boot drive?

Comment: I'm facing the same problem. I feel like it was better in the BIOS+MBR days, since we didn't have to deal with a vfat partition and could use any fs our kernel supported

Comment: Related: https://serverfault.com/questions/826304/btrfs-raid-and-booting-from-efi-system-partition - Somewhat related: https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=267870

Comment: After more research, it looks like the boot partition needs to be mirrored by md raid: https://www.reddit.com/r/btrfs/comments/4nlwkr/need_help_setting_up_btrfs_raid_1/d467wbn/